# Como puedo esconder un TextView cuando cambia la orientacion del Dispositivo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

estoy comenzando con Android Studio y me encuentro en un problema. como puedo hacer para que cuando el dispositivo que usa mi App, No muestre ciertos textview si esta vertical, y si los muestre cuando esta horizontal?
Intente cosas que no funcionaron para nada, la mayoría fue un crash.

Comment: Hola Ariel, por favor, agrega lo que has intentado, posiblemente solo es un cambio menor el que necesitas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la orientación del dispositivo mediante `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` para de esta forma determinar mostrar u ocultar la vista mediante `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

---

Ejemplo, si la orientación es vertical, esconde la vista:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) { //Orientación horizontal
    myTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Muestra vista.
} else { //Orientación Vertical
    myTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Esconde vista.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar esto

```
   @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```